# using stl list and class in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl

What do I need to write (in "?!?!?!")
if I want to printing all the names by the iterator iter?
the class have only name, c

```
//the code
    class H {
        string name;
    public :
        H (string n="WWW"): name(n){}
        string getName()const{return name;};
    };

    void main ()
    {
        H h1("HHH");
        H h2;
        list<H*> HH;
        list<H*>::iterator iter=HH.begin();

        HH.insert(iter,h1);
        HH.insert(iter,h2);

        for (; iter != HH.end(); iter++)
            cout<<iter  //?!?!?!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout << (*iter)->getName() << '\n';`

or whatever separator you want other than newline.

Also, your `insert` lines are wrong because `h1` and `h2` have type `H`, whereas the container is of `H*`.

Comment: @ChristianRapp: that's not correct. `insert` increases the size of the container, so although they're both inserted at the same position, the result is that the list contains two elements.